# How to create a return receipt email, Javamail

Tags: email, jakarta-mail

I am able to send an email using javamail with this code

```
message.setHeader("Disposition-Notification-To", from);
```

The above line sends a email which will request the user to send receipt or ignore request(using thunderbird i can see this message will popup).

How do i manually create a read receipt, to reply to this email so that the user knows i have "read" the email? (I know that reading will be ambiguous and up to users to decide but i just want to create a read receipt regardless)

Thanks.

Update:

```
DispositionNotification dn = new DispositionNotification();
MultipartReport mpr = new MultipartReport("This is a Return Receipt...", dn);
replyMessage.setContent(mpr);
```

The above is the code i used and it works, but it only shows the First part ("This is a ..."), what about the 2 other parts. There is MDNPart2.txt, and MDNPart3.txt.

Answer (score 1):

See the [com.sun.mail.dsn package](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/dsn/package-summary.html).

And read [RFC 3798 - Message Disposition Notification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3798.txt).

Create a MultipartReport object, populate it with a DispositionNotification object, the text to display to the user, and optionally the original message.  Use the Message.setContent method to set the MultipartReport as the content of the new message that you send back as the read receipt notification.